# How to Convert the delimitter in the following string

Tags: java, regex

```
String str =   "1000458551||A210171046D86F9F6EE21B66FE9B1441E20EC1DEF9654A2D092162591C01D26F||1||7707||0||0||1002||1373569142000||HTC One||val||4.1.2||0||1.01.20130206.15441";
str.replaceAll("(|\\|)", "|");
```

but the delimitter is not getting replaced, what am I doing wrong here?

Thanks for the reply in advance

Comment: what are you trying to replace

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main problem with your code is that you need to *assign* the String returned from calling `replace()`:

```
str = str.replace("||", "|");
```

In java, Strings are immutable - they can't be changed. String manipulation methods return a ^new String*, so to have any effect you must assign the returned value back to a variable - typically the *same* variable that held the String before the call.

Also, don't use `replaceAll()`, which uses regex for its search term. Instead use `replace()`, which still replaces all occurrences, but uses plain text for its search term. In regex, the pipe character has special meaning, so you'd need to escape each of them, which makes unnecessarily ugly code.

Comment: @user3218089 It seems you should accept this answer. Not mine.

Answer (score 0):

```
String newStr = str.replaceAll("\\|\\|", "|");
```